# Neo4j error : Failed authentication attempt for 'root' from 127.0.0.1

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have deployed my neo4j db on ec2. It was working fine untill a few days back when it started giving the error:

```
Failed authentication attempt for 'root' from 127.0.0.1
```

Ec2 is in perfect condition. What might be the reason that suddenly this neo4j has gone to halt? It was working perfectly before a few days. I did not even added much data to it.

This is the code to connect to neo4j database using sdn:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    return new SpringRestGraphDatabase(
            "http://52.73.217.65/db/data",
            "neo4j", 
            "mypass");
}
```

Comment: Is neo4j started? did you change the credentials? can you show us the code you are using to connect with neo4j?

Comment: Yes it started. And was working until recently.

Comment: I have added the code in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: If you are using neo4j as username, I don't know where this error message is coming from, because you don't try to log in as root. Where did you got this message?

Comment: I got this message in console.log file

Comment: There is no other errors in this file just this error is coming repeatedly.

Comment: Coming from java or from neo4j?

Comment: I did not even tried to change the password. It is the same which I set the first time.

Comment: it is coming from neo4j

Comment: in java it shows "503 service not available error"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86677/discussion-between-supamiu-and-anshul-goel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error showed on connection attempt was a `503 Service Not Available` one, meaning that neo4j was not running properly.

The problem was coming from corrupted neo4j setup, `/var/lib/neo4j` folder was empty, so the solution is to backup datas if they are still available and setup a new neo4j installation.